# Django model - how to go about this concept

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have a product model with the following:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    handle = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

Above is just the product detail, but there are 3 types of pricing:

1. Standard - normal regular pricing by filling the price field
2. Variant - pricing with product variants (size, colour, etc.) with their respective prices
3. Combined - this is a combination of other saved products, with a custom price provided by user.

For 1 and 2 I have the below model. If the product model has more than 1 price on StandardProduct model then I know it has variants.

```
class StandardProduct(models.Model):
    variant_type = models.CharField(max_length=55)
    variant_name = models.CharField(max_lenght=55)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=55, blank=True, null=True)
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=55, blank=True, null=True)
    selling_price = models.DecimalField(max_length=15, decimal_places=2)
```

**How do I go about creating the CombinedProduct model?** The combined product model can have different created products inside (with their quantities). The price is specified by the user. Below is what I have, but I don't know how to approach this.

```
class CombinedProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    item = models.ForeignKey(StandardProduct)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_length=15, decimal_places=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I go about creating the CombinedProduct model? The combined
>   product model can have different created products inside (with their
>   quantities). The price is specified by the user. Below is what I have,
>   but I don't know how to approach this.

What you probably want is a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) with [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) option.

This is just a very rough sketch up - I don't get your Product/StandardProduct and the relations.

```
class CombinedProduct(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField(
        Product,
        through='Combination'
    )


class Combination(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    combined_product = models.ForeignKey(CombinedProduct)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_length=15, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_length=15, decimal_places=2)
```

Comment: StandardProduct model has variations for a product, example: color (type), red (name), 500 (selling_price) and so on